# Customers with 75% of orders- SQL

Tags: sql

I have a file that contains customers with orders and I need to find the top 75%. It needs to be at least 75% and orders with the same number will be included. Need to figure out the where statement to select the records.

```
Cust   |  Orders |  Accum Orders  |  Accum %
c1           10               10     29%
c2            7               17     45%   
c3            5               22     63%
c4            4               26     74%
c5            3               29     83%
c6            3               32     89%
c7            2               34     94%
c8            1               35    100%
```

I would like to only extract c1-c6. C4 is only 74% and it needs to be 75%. c5-c6 are the same number of orders so they both need to be extracted.

Thanks

Comment: Hello @AprilRowe would you please provide the queries that you have tried, what results you are getting and what you expect your results to be so we can help you find the right method.

Comment: what is your target dbms?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by writing two queries and then make them union:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
  TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(ACCUMP,'%',''))  < 75 
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE ORDERS IN 
(
  SELECT ORDERS FROM TABLE1 
  GROUP BY ORDERS
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `subquery` with a `group by Orders`

```
select Cust
  from tab
 where Orders = 
    (
    select Orders
      from tab
      where replace(accum,'%','') >= 75
      group by Orders
      having count(AccumOrders) > 1
     );
```

[***Rextester Demo***](https://rextester.com/PGX70588)

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(orders) over (order by orders desc range between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_orders,
             sum(orders) over (partition by orders) as all_with_this_order,
             sum(orders) over () as total_orders
      from t
     ) t
where (running_orders - all_with_this_order) < 0.75 * total_orders;
```